# where is jsp's java file

Tags: tomcat

In tomcat6, where does tomcat put the generated java file for a JSP file?

exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jsp.xxx.yyy.view_jsp._jspService(view_jsp.java:164)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They're kept under Tomcat's `work` directory, e.g.

```
work/Catalina/localhost/_/org/apache/jsp/login_jsp.java
```

The specifics of the path my vary, from version to version, but it's always under `work`

Comment: work is the default location for the configuration of the output directory of the Jasper JSP Compiler. This can be changed by setting the property scratchdir in $CATALINA_BASE/conf/web.xml. Besides, the Java files may be deleted after compiling if the property keepgenerated is set to false. Source: "Apache Tomcat 6.0 - Jasper 2 JSP Engine How To" --- http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jasper-howto.html

Answer (score 4):

look in `${TOMCAT_HOME}/work/Catalina/<HOST>/....`